# scraping table with python based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, screen-scraping, scrape

since a week ago i have been trying to scrape a table from this site  https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx but i dont have an idea what to write,i am very confused.
iam trying to scrape table of kurs transaction from 2015-2020(20 nov 2015-20 nov 2020,
[image] but the problem is the link between the default date and the date that I chose is still the same.please help me in any way,Thank you before !

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers={
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}
url = "https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx"
import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get(url)
content= response.content
print(content)
```

Comment: i am unclear about what you mean by from 2015 to 2020? is there a way to generate that exact link? if so i can then attempt to code.

Comment: i want to get the data from 20 nov 2015 - 20 nov 2020,I have edited the question above

Comment: The issue is when you select two different dates it does not generate a query parameter in the url and as such you will need to use python selenium to do web scraping. I can certainly provide you code on how to scrape data from a table but you won't be able to use bs4 to scrape data for specific date.

Comment: thank you..then i have to install selenium first..about the code do you mind to tell me? or maybe just snipped of it..sorry because i really dont have an idea how to get it.thank you before!

Comment: I posted a solution that solves your date range problem. Now you can attempt to scrape the table that is generated and if you have trouble you can post that as a separate question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You can install Selenium and then you can install a [driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). I use chrome and then once you install it make a note of that path and set your `DRIVER_PATH` to the location

In the code below what i do is basically request the link you posted and then I enter the dates which you can change. Finally i click on the submit button. That generates the table within the date range. Now you can write follow up code to scrape the information from the table.

**Code**

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'Yourpath/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx')
start_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_biWebKursTransaksiBI_txtFrom")
start_date.send_keys("15-Nov-20")
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_biWebKursTransaksiBI_txtTo")
end_date.send_keys("20-Nov-20")
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_biWebKursTransaksiBI_btnSearch1").click()
```